# How can we execute SQL scripts in Big-query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new in GCP Big-query and I am able to execute SQL statement from cloud web UI.
Now I want to execute SQL script having multiple SQL statements, How can we do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigQuery scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery_scripting) which enables you to send multiple statements to BigQuery in one request, to use variables, and to use control flow statements such as IF and WHILE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BEGIN` and `END` to enclose multiple statements:

```
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE bq_poc.demo (demo_id INT64, demo_desc STRING);
  INSERT INTO bq_poc.demo VALUES(1, 'demo-1');
  INSERT INTO bq_poc.demo VALUES(2, 'demo-2');
  UPDATE bq_poc.demo SET demo_desc = 'demo-n' WHERE demo_id = 2;
  DELETE FROM bq_poc.demo WHERE demo_id = 2;
  SELECT * FROM bq_poc.demo;
END;
```